# WCF Webserice not being hit when Run

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to develop a wcf service using Visual Studio 2013 I have configured my web.config for the client details for my local hosts but its just not hitting the webservice at all. When i hit run it does indead open up the browser to http://localhost:4568/ but it doenst run the curoService my two files are called the following.

curoService.svc 
and its  constructor is set as follows.

```
public class curoService : IcuroService
```

and my interface constructor is set as

public interface IcuroService

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong no error message comes up its  just a blank browser window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="Curo.curoService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:4568/
                         Design_Time_Addresses/Curo/curoService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
             contract = "Curo.IcuroService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
               contract = "IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="curoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CuroDB.csdl|res://*/CuroDB.ssdl|res://*/CuroDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WIN-M71FFCH83PK\SQL14MOBILESERV;initial catalog=curo;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to trigger a call to your service. Hitting run in debug mode just attaches to the .net web development server, thus the blank page. Your browser is the client. In order to debug and step through, you have to trigger a server side method. Similar to:

htttp://localhost:4568/MyMethod?Param1='Test'

There are many useful tools that help you build out the messaging payload see  [WCF Test Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) just to name a few.

So you hit F12 to start and attach to the wcf server side process, set your break points, then open one of the tools and target your development endpoint.

**NOTE** : Also make sure you have the complete path defined. Right click the .svc file in the solution and select browse. This will bring up the metadata page that you can use to test with.

[image]

Comment: thanks im used to the old asmx services was nice interface so we could test the webservices so say i have my property contract GetPersonById I would do justhtttp://localhost:4568/GetPersonById?PersonId=1 ? does it have to be in same syntax as the method stub ie. string GetPersonById(int PersonId); mine is saying cant reach page though im sure that means configuration error?

Comment: I don't understand why your friendly page is not coming up in the browser. You have mexHttpBinding configured and httpGetsEnabled.

Comment: Ah...see the edited comment you have to specify the service name.

Comment: What you mine edit @IrbI dont see it where do u include the service name.

Comment: its k its comming up now as http://localhost:4568/curoService.svc so to test my json return i can just do http://localhost:4568/curoService.svc/GetPersonById?PersonId=1 ??? should that work

Comment: That is why I mentioned the tools above. If the metadata page does not allow you to fully test your service then I would use some of the more advanced tooling.

Comment: `There are many useful tools that help you build out the messaging payload see SoapUI, Fiddler and Wireshark just to name a few.` => Why aren't you naming the [WCF Test Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Hey Sébastien, when I started working with wcf I don't think there was a wcf test client toolset. I have always used another tool, just habit. I forgot to mention that one because I have never used it. I updated the answer to include it as well.

Comment: We all have our habits :-). I'm not saying that the WCF Test Client is the best tool, but is does it's job and does not require to install extra software so it deserved to be on the list.

Comment: Just one question in a wcf service being used to call from phone 8.1 project should i create async methods in my WCF service? or just normal methods fine?.